# Как сделать, чтобы drag and drop в js. при нажатии на элемент (картинку) создавал копию и переносил, а основной элемент(картинка) оставался на месте

Tags: javascript, drag, drop

```
   bead.onmousedown = function(event) {
        let shiftX = event.clientX - bead.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        let shiftY = event.clientY - bead.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      
        bead.style.position = 'absolute';
        bead.style.zIndex = 1000;
      
        moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);
      
        
        function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
            bead.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
            bead.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
        }
      
        function onMouseMove(event) {
          moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);
        }
      
        
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
      
       
        bead.onmouseup = function() {
          document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
          bead.onmouseup = null;
        };
    
      };
   
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="img/1.png" id="bead" />
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: можно html код? что такое bead?

Comment: bead - это id  к картинке
<img src="img/1.png" id="bead" />
Это весь код в html

Comment: Пытаюсь сделать конструктор браслетов. То есть пользователь должен нажимать на бусину (картинку) и перетащить копию бусины  на макет. Пока получилось сделать, чтобы бусина просто перемещалась по всему экрану.

Comment: https://codepen.io/ryanaltvater/pen/rGjMzj - есть пример на jquery

Comment: по вашему решению - внутри event onmousedown - добавьте в первой строке этой функции - 

 const beadClone = bead.cloneNode(true);
 const beadContainer = document.querySelector('.container');
 beadContainer.appendChild(beadClone);

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r3m80hnj/10/ вот попробовал в вашем варианте - может натолкнет на дальнейшие шаги

Comment: Спасибо, Ваше решение очень помогло!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно что-то такое сделать.. Клик удерживая shift удаляет картинку.

```js
let bead = document.querySelectorAll('.bead');
let playa = document.querySelector('#playa');

let flag = false, imgClone = null;

for (var elem of bead) elem.addEventListener('mousedown', addRemoveCopy);

function addRemoveCopy(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  flag = true;

  if (this.classList.contains('imgCopy')) {
  // Если нажали на клон с шифтом удалить. Иначе присвоить переменной imgClone - елемент на котором нажата кнопка мыши
    return e.shiftKey ? e.target.remove() : imgClone = e.target;
  }

  imgClone = e.target.cloneNode();
  imgClone.setAttribute('class', 'imgCopy');
  imgClone.addEventListener('mousedown', addRemoveCopy);
  playa.append(imgClone);
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (!flag || !imgClone) return;
  let box = imgClone.getBoundingClientRect();
  imgClone.style.left = e.pageX - box.width / 2 + 'px';
  imgClone.style.top = e.pageY - box.height / 2 + 'px';
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  imgClone = null;
  flag = false;
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px inset black;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  /*скрыть полосу прокрутки*/
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
#container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

#playa {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px inset black;
  background: #F0F0F0;
}

img {
  height: 75px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.imgCopy {
  position: absolute;
  /*
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://www.dorogavrim.ru/img/flagi/flag_rossiya.jpg" class="bead" />
  <img src="https://www.dorogavrim.ru/img/flagi/flag_ukraina.jpg" class="bead" />
  <img src="https://www.dorogavrim.ru/img/flagi/flag_belarus.jpg" class="bead" />
  <img src="https://www.dorogavrim.ru/img/flagi/flag_serbiya.jpg" class="bead" />
  <img src="https://www.dorogavrim.ru/img/flagi/flag_rossiya.jpg" class="bead" />
  <img src="https://www.dorogavrim.ru/img/flagi/flag_ukraina.jpg" class="bead" />
</div>
<div id='playa'></div>
```

Comment: Да, это функция для меня полезна. Спасибо!

Comment: @НастенаПрунь На здоровье! :)

Comment: Можно еще один вопрос. Как сделать, чтобы картинки не наезжали друг на друга. Если рассматривать Ваш пример, чтобы флаги не накладывались друг на друга. Можно не кодом, а хотя бы в каком направлении искать информацию

Comment: @НастенаПрунь Можно наблюдать за пересечением при помощи [Intersection_Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) при пересечении выполнять конечные действия из mouseup и выставлять координаты перетаскиваемому блоку, если перетаскивали справа налево его Y = Y а X будет равен X+width блока с которым он пересекся ..

Comment: Еще раз спасибо огромное!

Comment: На здоровье! :)